Cournot collusion with asymmetric costs
How can the optimal share of total quantity between two firms in a collusion with asymmetric costs be determined?

Can you please set up the problem that you're working on? It is otherwise difficult to know the assumptions you have on your mind. By "Cournot collusion", do you mean tacit collusion in a Cournot model?

It is tacit collusion in a Cournot model. There are two firms with constant but different marginal costs. The game is repeated for infinite periods.
